# Guarded Blocks with Join

Tags: java, multithreading, join, guard

I need to synchronize over several threads. I don't create the threads, but I do know how many there are. So I wrote this inner guarded block:

```
private class Guard {
    int waiters = 0;
    boolean wait;
    synchronized void addWaiter() {
        ++waiters;
        wait = true;
        while (wait && waiters != threadNum()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        waiters = 0;
        wait = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

This guarded block is executed in a loop. So the problem is that it might get called a second time before all the threads from the first call are released from the `wait()` loop, which obviously screws up the whole logic of the guard. So I need to have the threads join somehow before they are released from the guard. Is there a design for this? What is the most elegant way of accomplishing it. Keep in mind that the threads are not created by me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).  You can set the latch to wait for N count downs. See the Javadoc for examples.

Comment: Aha!! That should so it. I reinvented the wheel. Unfortunately, it was square.

Comment: Tyre companies re-invent the wheel all the time, but that's their job. I tend to leave the concurrency stuff to the experts. ;)

Comment: Just as a side note, in this case CyclicBarrier seems like a better candidate. It is the reusable cousin of the CountDownLatch.

Comment: To continue delmet's analogy Java 7 is coming out with Phaser, it is the offspring of countdownlatch and cyclicbarrier :)